# String to nested Object parser

Tags: java

***Hi***

I am writing a graphical interface program to solve chemical equations and to be other functions such as displaying a periodic table in a different window.

As the title suggests I'm having issues with the string to objects parser and would like some help with getting it to work.

It gets a `String` formula (`C6H14 + O2 => CO2 + H2O`) and will divide it up into different objects (Molecule(s) has a list of Element(s) which store the name and quantity), which then is returned. Note* I have it set as `void` for testing purposes only.

I have split the functions into two parts: The first part reads the `String` into Element objects; a name and a quantity. The second part makes the Molecule objects and checks where one molecule starts and another one ends and places the element object accordingly. This is why I do not filter away the numerical actions such as `+`, `=` and `>`.

Parser:

```
    public void formatFormula(String formula) {
    List[] temp = new List[] {
        new ArrayList<Molecule>(),
        new ArrayList<Molecule>()
    };
    List<Element> ell = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean newMol = true;
    String crnN = null;
    int crnQ=0;
    int side = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<formula.length()+1;i++) {
        String d;
        try { d = formula.substring(i,i+1); } catch (Exception e) { d = formula.substring(i-1); }
        if (Character.isWhitespace(d.charAt(0))) continue;

        if (isNumber(d)) {
            crnQ = Integer.parseInt(crnQ+d);
        } else if (d == d.toUpperCase()) {
            if (crnN != null)
                ell.add(new Element(crnN,crnQ));
            crnN = d;
            crnQ = 0;
        } else {
            crnN = crnN + d;
        }
    }
    Element e;
    for (int i=0;i<ell.size();i++) {
        e = ell.get(i);
        if (e.getName().charAt(0) == "+".charAt(0)) {
            newMol = true;
            continue;
        }
        if (e.getName().charAt(0) == "=".charAt(0) || e.getName().charAt(0) == ">".charAt(0)) {
            newMol = true;
            side = 1;
            continue;
        }

        if (newMol) {
            temp[side].add(new Molecule());
            newMol=false;
        } else {
            ((Molecule)temp[side].get(temp[side].size()-1)).addElement(e);
        }
    }
    // Debugging.
    for (Object f:temp[1]) {
        System.out.println(((Molecule) f).getElements().get(0).getName());

    }
}
```

The values that I get out of it is completely wrong. The second list on side `2` is empty, list `1` and `2` on side `2` has the same value and none of the Molecule objects have more than one element.

It should return a 2D array of Molecules, one before the arrow and one after. Those Molecule objects store the Element objects.

Input:
`C6H14 + O2 => CO2 + H2O`
Output:

```
    C6H14         +     O2              =>     CO2            +     H2O
Obj(Molecule){    | Obj(Molecule){      || Obj(Molecule){     | Obj(Molecule){
Obj(Element){C:6} | Obj(Element){O:2}}  || Obj(Element){C:1}  | Obj(Element){H:2}
Obj(Element){H:14}}                     || Obj(Element){O:2}} | Obj(Element){O:1}}
```

Note* this is just a representation of the objects. But `Molecule`s store a list of `Element`s which in turn store a `String` and a `int` value.

Comment: Can you post examples of input and expected output?

Comment: @ggorlen Updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a temporary Molecule object variable which then are inserted into the list.

```
public Molecule[][] ParseString(String formula) {
List[] temp = new List[] {
    new ArrayList<Molecule>(),
    new ArrayList<Molecule>()
};
List<Element> ell = new ArrayList<>();
String crnN = null;
int crnQ=0;
int side = 0;
for (int i=0;i<formula.length()+1;i++) {
    String d;
    try { d = formula.substring(i,i+1); } catch (Exception e) { d = formula.substring(i-1); }
    if (Character.isWhitespace(d.charAt(0))) continue;

    if (isNumber(d)) {
        crnQ = Integer.parseInt(crnQ+d);
    } else if (d == d.toUpperCase()) {
        if (crnN != null)
            ell.add(new Element(crnN,crnQ));
        crnN = d;
        crnQ = 0;
    } else {
        crnN = crnN + d;
    }
}

Molecule tempM = new Molecule();
boolean newMol = false;
for (Element e:ell) {
    String n = e.getName();

    if (n.charAt(0) == "+".charAt(0)) {
        newMol = true;
        temp[side].add(tempM);
        tempM = new Molecule();
    }
    if (n.charAt(0) == "=".charAt(0)) {
        newMol = true;
        if (side == 0)
            temp[side].add(tempM);
        side = 1;
        tempM = new Molecule();
    }
    if (n.charAt(0) == ">".charAt(0)) {
        side = 1;
        tempM = new Molecule();
        continue;
    }
    if (newMol) {
        newMol = false;
    } else {
        tempM.addElement(e);
    }
}
temp[1].add(tempM);

return new Molecule[][]{
        ((Molecule[]) temp[0].toArray(new Molecule[temp[0].size()])),
        ((Molecule[]) temp[1].toArray(new Molecule[temp[1].size()]))
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty weird code.

I suggest few refactorings

1) Split your formula using "=>" string and get two formulas (left and right) which you can parse separately.

```
String delim="=>";
int p=s.indexOf(delim); 
String left=s.substring(0, p); 
String right=s.substring(p+delim.length());
List<Molecule> leftMolecules=parse(left);
List<Molecule> rightMolecules=parse(right);
```

2) Create function `parse` which parses tokens of your formula

```
List<Molecule> parse(String formula) {
  String [] molecules = formula.split("\\+"); // + is special character and requires escaping
  List<Molecule> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for (String m : molecules) {
     m = m.trim(); // remove leading and trailing spaces
     // here you parse single molecule like H2O etc
     ...
  }
  return result;
}
```